# If a router is seemingly blocking VPN usage, is there a way around it?

Tags: macos, router, vpn, isp

Background: I'm staying at an Airbnb, so I'm using the internet through a router and ISP that are unknown to me. And I have no access to the router unless I'm going to try to get my host to do work on it for me. I'm on a macbook pro.

I use the Global Protect VPN app to connect to a certain client's network, but it won't connect now that I am here. Is it possible that my host's router is set up in a way that doesn't allow VNP traffic to work correctly? Is there any way around it?

Comment: If you are staying for a very long time, ask the proprietor, otherwise use your phone as a hotspot when you need VPN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ways to avoid VPN blocks:

- Use your phone as hotspot
- Use the [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/)
- Use [Shadowsocks](https://shadowsocks.org/en/index.html)
  (Chinese application, very popular in China for obvious reasons)
- Use [Psiphon](https://psiphon.ca/) that lets you try multiple connection
  methods and protocols.